# Perl printing array values getting weird

Tags: arrays, perl, split, compare

I am experiencing something that i don't understand here's my code :

```
    @iprouteur = split( /./, $arraylist[1] );
    print "lip du routeur est $arraylist[1]\n";
    for ( $i = 2; $i <= $#arraylist; $i++ ) {
        print "we found secondary which is $arraylist[$i]\n";
        @secondary = split( /./, $arraylist[$i] );
        print "voici les ip a comparer : $iprouteur[0] $iprouteur[1] $iprouteur[2] et $secondary[0] $secondary[1] $secondary[2] \n";
        if ( $iprouteur[0] eq $secondary[0] && $iprouteur[1] eq $secondary[1] && $iprouteur[2] eq $secondary[2] ) {
            print "we need to splice \n";
        }
    }
```

The output is like :

```
lip du routeur est 126.x.x.x
we found secondary which is 126.x.x.x/24
voici les ip a comparer :    et
we need to splice
```

Why perl can't find what is inside the **$iprouteur[x]** and **$secondary[y]** variable ?

Comment: Fun fact: When you interpolate an array (slice), the elements are separated by spaces. So you can do `" ... @ipproteur[0,1,2] .."`

Comment: Are you using `use strict; use warnings;`?

Comment: You mean that i can use if (@iprouteur[0,1,2] eq @secondary[0,1,2]) ?

Comment: No, I meant what it said, that you can interpolate them in double quoted strings. E.g. `print "@foo[0,1,2]"` is the same as `print "$foo[0] foo[1] $foo[2]"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you split with the regex `/./`. The period `.` is a meta character, and it is the wildcard, matching any char except newline. So it consumes your entire string when used, and returns a bunch of empty strings. The solution is to escape the period:

```
@secondary = split(/\./, $arraylist[$i]);
#                   ^--- note the backslash
```

Also what I meant in the comments is that this line:

```
print "voici les ip a comparer : $iprouteur[0] $iprouteur[1] $iprouteur[2] et $secondary[0] $secondary[1] $secondary[2] \n";
```

can be written:

```
print "voici les ip a comparer : @iprouteur[0,1,2] et @secondary[0,1,2] \n";
```

Which is easier both to read and to write.

Comment: Thanks, i realized it when you were writting it :)

Comment: Sometimes you just need a fresh pair of eyes on your problem.

Answer (score 2):

My bad, i forgot to use "." with the split function

I forgot that it was a special char.

```
@iprouteur = split(/\./,$arraylist[1]);
@secondary = split(/\./, $arraylist[$i]);
```

Comment: note that enabling warnings would have alerted you to this (because the arrays produced are empty so the elements you try to look up are undef)

Comment: Writing Perl code without `use strict; use warnings;` is a very bad idea. You might think it is easier, but that is only because your errors are hidden.